# keeping table rows that match the other table

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I need some help with this problem:
I have two tables and I want to filter the rows on the second table (Table B) so that it only shows the one's that have matching 'names' with the Table A.

An exemple:

Table A

| A | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anne | Two | Three |
| Anne | Four | Five |
| Jhon | Four | Five |
| Olivia | Four | Five |

Table. B

| A | Money | Rent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anne | Two | Three |
| Anne | Four | Five |
| Anne | Four | Five |
| Kristian | Four | Five |
| Paul | Four | Five |
| Olivia | Four | Five |
| Olivia | Four | Five |

The result that I want to achieve is

| A | Money | Rent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anne | Two | Three |
| Anne | Four | Five |
| Anne | Four | Five |
| Jhon | Nan | Nan |
| Olivia | Four | Five |
| Olivia | Four | Five |

Comment: Jhon is not in Table B, which makes your instructions a bit unclear. Do you mean only keep in Table B the names that appear in Table A, and also add in Table B the ones that appear in Table A but do not appear in Table B (as NaN)?

Comment: Exactly! I want to keep in the Table B the names that appear in table A but at the same time I want to add the ones that are not in B as Nan

Answer (score 3):

You can `isin` and `append`:

```
# Create a new B table that only includes the names of A table
new_b = b.loc[b['A'].isin(a['A'].tolist())]

# Append the additional names from Table A (i.e. Jhon)
new_b = new_b.append(a.loc[~a['A'].isin(new_b['A'].tolist())]).drop(['b','c'],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Prints:

```
        A Money   Rent
0    Anne   Two  Three
1    Anne  Four   Five
2    Anne  Four   Five
3  Olivia  Four   Five
4  Olivia  Four   Five
5    Jhon   NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `pandas`, you could try this: `dfC = dfB[dfB['A'].isin(dfA['A'].unique())]`

This way, you will be filtering table B, based on it's A column, looking for values that are in the column A of table A.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_B WHERE A IN (SELECT A FROM table_A)

Answer (score 0):

using `df.join` could get the job done for you.

```
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['Anne','Anne','Jhon','Olivia'],B=[2,2,4,5],C=[3,5,5,5]))  
dfB = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['Anne','Anne','Anne','Kristan','Paul','Olivia','Olivia'],
                        Money=[2,4,4,4,4,4,4],Rent=[3,5,5,5,5,5,5]))
dfB = dfB.set_index('A')
dfA.groupby('A').first().join(dfB).loc[:,['Money','Rent']]
        Money  Rent
A
Anne      2.0   3.0
Anne      4.0   5.0
Anne      4.0   5.0
Jhon      NaN   NaN
Olivia    4.0   5.0
Olivia    4.0   5.0
```

edit: further explanation of last line

`groupby('A').first()` creates a dataframe of the unique names, arbitrarily choosing the first entry for columns B and C (since you want to get rid of those anyways). Then `.join(dfB)` does a left join using the unique values of table A as the left table, and dfB as the right table. `loc[:,['Money','Rent']]` chooses the columns you want (removing the B and C columns from table A).